# How can I get the average of an array of struct which includes 5 students grades?

Tags: c

This is the code I have, I am fairly new to C. I retrieve 5 students names and grades from a txt file. I then have to calculate the average of each students grades. I am really confused and lost lol, any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the info I have on the txt file:

```
James
Smith
40 60 70 90 100
Will
Jones
20 21 22 23 24
Jose
Lopez
25 26 27 28 29
Jesus
Diaz
30 31 32 33 34
Iker
Caz
35 36 37 38 39
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fp;

int main() {
    int i, j, avg, average, num;
    //Structure which contains elements for the students info//
    struct student {
        char fname[10];
        char lname[10];
        int grade[5];
        int avggrade;
    } student[5];
    
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    
    //reads file and retrives each students data//
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", student[i].fname);
        fscanf(fp, "%s", student[i].lname);
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &student[i].grade[j]);
        }
    }
    //prints out each students data so you can see that the file was read correctly//
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", student[i].fname);
        printf("%s\n", student[i].lname);
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", student[i].grade[j]);
        }
    }
    
    //Find average//
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        sum = student[2].grade[j] + sum;    
    }
    printf("%.2f", sum);
}
```

Comment: You already know how to iterate the students and grades. So in the same way you just need to keep the sum of the grades for each student and then divide by 5. Can you be more specific regarding what problem you have?

Comment: Also, one should average the grade for all students; that involves a loop (`i` in students) within a loop (`j` in grades,) in much the same way that one prints, but you will need an _accumulator_ variable to add them up, (as is `sum`.)

Comment: Avoid the use of *global* variables. `fp` is more properly declared in `main()` and passed as a parameter to any function that may need to read from the open steam. Also, you want to VALIDATE the file is open for reading by ***checking the return***. E.g. `if (fp == NULL) { perror ("file-open file.txt failed"); return 1; }` (same for every input to the program as well, especially with `fscanf()`, e.g. `if (fscanf(fp, "%s", student[i].fname) != 1) { /* handle error */}`)

Answer (score 1):

Just look at your loop and think about how it will work.  It will never run because `j<n` is false on the first iteration, when both of those variables are equal to 0.